# Как сделать чтобы ячейка не создавалась если она пустая

Tags: php

```
if($value == 'mtimein' ){
?><td><?=$val['mtimein']?></td>                         
<?                      
}
```

Подскажите как сделать так что если нету значения в ячейке mtimein то не создается ячейка  если значение есть то ячейка создается и выводит содержимое, пробовал дописывать empty в условии и на пустоту писал, не работало.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще кратко и правильно будет так

```
<?=!empty($val['mtimein']) ? '<td>'.$val['mtimein'].'</td>' : ''?>
```

Но раз Вы пробовали писать условие на `empty` и не срабатывало значит у Вас в `$val['mtimein']` хранится не то что Вы предполагаете. Попробуйте сделать `var_dump($val['mtimein'])` и убедиться что там действительно нет никаких невидимых символов или прочего.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, что таблица у вас создается в цикле и это часть кода для отрисовки заполненных полей сделайте так:

```
$flag = 0; // доп. переменная

for($i=0; $i<count($val); $i++) // прогоняете ваш массив val в цикле
{
    if ($value === "mtimein") {
        $a = "<td>";
        $a .= $val[$i]['mtimein'];
        $a .= "</td>";

        echo $a; // вывод ячейки

        $flag = 1; // изменение доп. переменной
    }
}
```

А при сравнении `$flag` с 0 можно делать действия с пустыми клетками таблицы, когда `$value !== "mtimein"`